# Get access of launcher screen while showing activity content?

Tags: android, uiactivityindicatorview, android-windowmanager

is it possible to get touch access of launcher while showing activity?
while activity covering only quarter of screen area only.

Comment: thanks WebnetMobile.com...surely will take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

as i said make an activity layout which cover quarter area of screen, I added flag for activity `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);`

it works :) to get access of launcher screen, even my activity is open. I notice another one thing i m not able to get click event on launcher, nor getting focus from my activity to launcher, it's just giving me touch event on launcher.

any one have idea over this, how can i get focus from my activity to launcher or any open application.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com : do u have any idea/suggestion about this problem?